# GCC 4.7, including <stdatomic.h>

Tags: gcc, include, atomic, gcc4.7

I've just compiled GCC 4.7 to work with `stdatomic.h`, but I can't seem to `-I` it. `stdatomic.h` seems to live in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.3`, but then the linker tells me it needs a bunch of other files in dirs nearby. If I `-I` all of them, I still get the error `undefined reference to atomic_flag_clear_explicit`. Any ideas how I'm supposed to link this right?

Comment: Didn't the 4.7 source package come with a 4.7 libstdc++ as well?

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean I may be linking to the wrong include? Let me see.

Comment: @K.G. `<stdatomic.h>` is standard C, not C++.

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct compiler? Try `gcc --version` to see what version you are using. You might want to use `gcc-4.7` instead to make sure you get the correct compiler, which will have all correct paths built in.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, I compiled it with "--program-suffix=-4.7", so it is calling the right version.

Comment: I still can't do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly your gcc installation is borked

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are compiling with GCC 4.7 you should not be including or linking *anything* from a directory from GCC 4.4.

Second, `-I` only affects the search path for header files. "undefined reference" is a linker error and usually means it hasn't found the right library. You change the library search path with `-L`. The linker didn't say it didn't find a library with the right name, it says it didn't find a symbol, so clearly the library it did find didn't have that symbol. I'd suggest you have a versioning problem, perhaps caused by a installation problem.

Answer (score 2):

The <stdatomic.h> header in GCC 4.4 and 4.5 was from an early draft of C++0x atomics, but is not part of the final standard, so it was removed from libstdc++.

The C++ compiler supports C++11 atomics via the C++11 <atomic> header, so you should use that header in C++ code.

When the C compiler supports C11 atomics, the <stdatomic.h> header will be provided again.

Answer (score 0):

Using this command solved the problem for me:

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```

I got the same error as you when entering `sudo make altinstall` for installing Python 3.8.5 on CentOS 7.